# Do not parse null values in toJson()

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to skip doing anything with a value if it is null in the toJson method of an object ?

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'fullName': fullName,
    'email': mail,
    'password': password,
    'city': city,
    'company': company,
    'keywords': keywords,
    'location': location,
  };
```

Because I don't want null fields to reach my db.

Ex.: 
User(city: "LA") returns: fullName:null, email:null, password:null, city: 'LA', company: null ...

While I want it to return just city:'LA'

Comment: Yes, thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for x)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This should work

```dart
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => ({
    'fullName': fullName,
    'email': mail,
    'password': password,
    'city': city,
    'company': company,
    'keywords': keywords,
    'location': location,
  }).removeWhere((key, value) => value != null);
```

Comment: This would throw an exception because removeWhere returns void.

Comment: Also it would remove all non-null fields, which is the opposite of what Tom was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this to remove null fields

```
User.removeWhere((key, value) => value==null);
```